# How to import libraries from another directory with python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm developing python application using Google Application Engine.
Error occurs when importing libraries if directory structure and code are below:

Directory structure

```
Application
├── src
│   ├── main.py
└── lib
    ├── oauth2
    │   └── files
    └── __init__.py
```

Source code

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.pardir + "/lib"))
import oauth2
```

Error messages

```
ERROR    2015-01-23 17:48:55,226 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/path/to/src/main.py", line 152, in <module>
    import oauth2
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 934, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
```

I tried these codes as below, but all of them raise me same errors...

case1

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.pardir + "/lib")
import oauth2
```

case2 .. I am almost abandonment

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir) + "/lib")
import oauth2
```

**Only the directory structure and code as below works**

Directory structure

```
Application
└── src
    ├── main.py
    ├── oauth2
    │   └── files
    └── __init__.py
```

Source code

```
import oauth2
```

***UPDATE***

This is not working.

Directory structure

```
Application
├── src
│   ├── main.py
└── lib
    ├── oauth2
    │   └── files
    └── __init__.py
```

Source code

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.pardir + "/lib"))
from lib import oauth2
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely running afoul of the Python sandbox, which tries to ensure imports will succeed or fail on your local development environment exactly as they will in production once you deploy there (since its focus is indeed to help you develop locally stuff that's meant for production deployment once ready and well tested).

The sandbox gets control before your `main.py` does and among other things it sets up its checks based on the initial value of `sys.path`, independently from further changes you may be doing it it.

However your original directory structure should be fine -- just change your

```
import oauth2
```

to

```
from lib import oauth2
```

and you should be good to go (package `lib` **is** in your `sys.path` from the start as it resides in your main directory -- and it **is** a package thanks to the existence of that little precious `__init__.py` file:-).

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work in my local environment. I added this pattern on my question.

Comment: So what's in those `files`?  I see you don't show an `oauth2.py`, but, do you have an `oauth2/__init__.py`?

Comment: oauth2 directory is exactly this -> https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/tree/master/oauth2 . And I added httplib2 into oauth2 directory  https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/tree/master/python2/httplib2 .